# Blender and exported .obj files exceeding 2GB even after decimation & limited dissolve

Tags: modeling, export, blend-files

First of all, I am not all that professional working with blender, which made me very proud, that I was able to come up with a complex model which is supposed to be used for a 3D crystal engraving business. Naturally, as I am not a pro, I most likely used a lot of walk arounds and have probably used design methods, any pro would have done simpler, easier and more effective. But for me, optically I am happy with it.

It is a very complex and detailed model of a village in Austria and so far it looks good but it just got to large. The blender file is about 920MB with compressed storage while the exported .obj file is 2.4GB and all that without any During the process I have decimated the model to the limits and also applied various limited dissolve operations as well as I have resized it.

My question would be, what else can I do to get this model smaller in size and ist it normal for complex models like this to blow up to that poinnt? The point cloud conversion software rejects it most likely because of the size.

The attached pic of the model is some 2 weeks old and by now there is more details like trees, boats etc in the model. The pic was taken before I applied the decimate modifier and limited dissolve.

Tnx a lot in advance for your help.[image][image]

Comment: please can you show at least the vertex/edge/face count that appears on the window top right? I guess it's a single object?

Comment: Tnx for your reply. It is enormously large. 36.000.000 Verts, 11.500.000 Faces, 22.000.000 Tris. - And that is after decimate and limited resolve.

Comment: And yes, you are right, I have a backup with the individual meshes but this one is a single object.

Comment: Well having it as one single giant mesh and applying modifiers certainly wont help in file size. You could have been taking advantage of instancing clones, and mesh procedural generation. That would have helped in he blend file size department at least, obj would still be constrained to the final polycount. The model doesn't look that high-poly, certainly not 900Mb worth of high poly

Comment: Tnx a lot for having a look at it. As mentioned, I still have the backup blender file with all the individual meshes. But no earthly idea, how this large file size comes together. Unfortunately I am not a pro and not familiar with procedural generation (I guess it deals with blender's python scripting) ,that would unfortunately not be an option on my level. Not really sure though, how to approach this issue.